# ResNet model in Tensorflow Federated

Tags: tensorflow, resnet, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I tried to customize the model in "Image classification" tutorial in Tensorflow Federated. (It originally used a sequential model)
I use Keras ResNet50 but when it began to train, there is always an error "Incompatible shapes"

Here are my codes:

```
NUM_CLIENTS = 4
NUM_EPOCHS = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 2
SHUFFLE_BUFFER = 5

def create_compiled_keras_model():
  model = tf.keras.applications.resnet.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', 
                                                input_tensor=tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(100, 
                                                300, 3)), pooling=None)

  model.compile(
      loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.02),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
  return model


def model_fn():
  keras_model = create_compiled_keras_model()
  return tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model(keras_model, sample_batch)

iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn)
```

Error information:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Ctu.png)

I feel that the shape is incompatible because the epoch and clients information were somehow missing. Would be very thankful if someone could give me a hint.

**Updates:**

The Assertion error happened during `tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-164-dac26193d9d8> in <module>()
----> 1 iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn)
      2 
      3 # iterative_process = build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn)

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/federated_averaging.py in build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn, server_optimizer_fn, client_weight_fn, stateful_delta_aggregate_fn, stateful_model_broadcast_fn)
    165   return optimizer_utils.build_model_delta_optimizer_process(
    166       model_fn, client_fed_avg, server_optimizer_fn,
--> 167       stateful_delta_aggregate_fn, stateful_model_broadcast_fn)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/framework/optimizer_utils.py in build_model_delta_optimizer_process(model_fn, model_to_client_delta_fn, server_optimizer_fn, stateful_delta_aggregate_fn, stateful_model_broadcast_fn)
    349   # still need this.
    350   with tf.Graph().as_default():
--> 351     dummy_model_for_metadata = model_utils.enhance(model_fn())
    352 
    353   # ===========================================================================

<ipython-input-159-b2763ace8e5b> in model_fn()
      1 def model_fn():
      2   keras_model = model
----> 3   return tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model(keras_model, sample_batch)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/keras_utils.py in from_compiled_keras_model(keras_model, dummy_batch)
    211   # Model.test_on_batch() once before asking for metrics.
    212   if isinstance(dummy_tensors, collections.Mapping):
--> 213     keras_model.test_on_batch(**dummy_tensors)
    214   else:
    215     keras_model.test_on_batch(*dummy_tensors)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in test_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, reset_metrics)
   1007         sample_weight=sample_weight,
   1008         reset_metrics=reset_metrics,
-> 1009         standalone=True)
   1010     outputs = (
   1011         outputs['total_loss'] + outputs['output_losses'] + outputs['metrics'])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in test_on_batch(model, x, y, sample_weight, reset_metrics, standalone)
    503       y,
    504       sample_weights=sample_weights,
--> 505       output_loss_metrics=model._output_loss_metrics)
    506 
    507   if reset_metrics:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    568         xla_context.Exit()
    569     else:
--> 570       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    571 
    572     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    606       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
    607       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
--> 608       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
    609       if self._created_variables:
    610         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2407     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
   2408     with self._lock:
-> 2409       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2410     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2411 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2765 
   2766       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 2767       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2768       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2769       return graph_function, args, kwargs

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2655             arg_names=arg_names,
   2656             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2657             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2658         self._function_attributes,
   2659         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    979         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    980 
--> 981       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    982 
    983       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    437         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    438         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 439         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    440     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    441 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

AssertionError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py:345 test_on_batch  *
        with backend.eager_learning_phase_scope(0):
    /usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py:81 __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py:425 eager_learning_phase_scope
        assert ops.executing_eagerly_outside_functions()

    AssertionError:
```

Comment: Please copy your stack trace as text, instead of posting it as an image.

Comment: Great question! Can we see where `sample_batch` is coming from?

Comment: Sorry I tried commenting in code format but it looked so messy. `sample_batch` is training data in a batch. For example, if the batch size is 2, then `sample_batch` is `OrderedDict([('x', array([], []), ('y', array([], []))])`

Comment: Please can you see this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60060493/tff-invalid-argument-default-maxpoolingop-only-supports-nhwc-on-device-type-cp

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I believe this issue is coming from mismatched expectations on `sample_batch`. TFF passes `sample_batch` to Keras, which calls a forward pass with this sample batch to initialize various attributes of the keras model. `sample_batch` should be either a sample from the literal data you are going to be feeding the model as on the server side, or a batch of fake data which matches the shape and type of the data you will be passing in.

An example of the former can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/baselines/emnist/run_federated.py#L97) (this uses `tf.data.Dataset`), and there are several examples of the latter in test code, like [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/federated_averaging_test.py#L137).

From what I see of the definition of the model, likely the `x` element of your sample_batch should be an `ndarray` of shape `[2, 100, 300, 3]` (where 2 is for the batch size, but technically this can be any nonzero dimension), and the `y` element should also match the expected `y` structure in the data you are using.

I hope this helps, just ping back if there are any problems!

One thing to note, that may be helpful in thinking about TFF--TFF is building a syntax tree representing the distributed computation you are defining via `build_federated_averaging_process`. This error actually occurs during *construction* of this object. TFF must trace the computation you pass it in order to know what structure to generate, and this is what is raising here. Actual *training* of the model happens when you call `next` on the returned `IterativeProcess`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I adjust the output layer of the model to match my y shape and solved the shame incompatible problem. I successfully got a `tff.learning.model` from tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model, but when I run `iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn)` ,  there is a AssertionError: which is really hard to track. Have spent a lot of time but no idea how it came. Could you please give me any suggestions?
The error was attached in the update of the question.

Comment: Hm, this is interesting, we just saw something like this from another source. I'll dig in

Comment: Sounds good! Please feel free to let me know for any findings. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just a quick update: we've been diving deep on an internal repro, almost ready to file a bug--as far as we can tell, something inside of Keras training is not being set correctly for some reason. I'll link that bug here if/when we file it.

Comment: Cool! And not sure if the information helps but I found that the assertion happened when I applied Keras Model class, even though I just use the class to set 1 dense layer. However, if I use keras.sequential(), there's no such issue. And applications like keras.applications.resnet.ResNet50 has no issue either.

Comment: There is a hypothesis leading to the following suggestion: wherever you import tensorflow in your script, can you try moving the line `tf.compat.v1.enable_v2_behavior()` to *the next line* after this import?

Comment: I removed this line but still got the same error...:( 
Should I try disabling v2 behavior?

Comment: It was solved! It turned out that the model has to be built and returned in `create_compiled_keras_model()`, rather than be built outside the function, which might be the reason!

Comment: Ah, yes, this makes sense. TFF needs to control virtually everything about model instantiation (especially since instantiating a model can create `tf.Variables`, which may not play well with the remainder of the TF/TFF runtime). Glad to hear there is a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem:
if I execute this line 
state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)
print('round 1, metrics={}'.format(metrics))

I find this error
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Default MaxPoolingOp only supports NHWC on device type CPU
     [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/sequential/vgg16/block1_pool/MaxPool}}]]
     [[subcomputation/StatefulPartitionedCall_1/ReduceDataset]]
     [[subcomputation/StatefulPartitionedCall_1/ReduceDataset/_140]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Default MaxPoolingOp only supports NHWC on device type CPU
     [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/sequential/vgg16/block1_pool/MaxPool}}]]
     [[subcomputation/StatefulPartitionedCall_1/ReduceDataset]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

knowin that I employe VGG16
have you any idea on this type of error